# Invert matrix in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this matrix in Scala:

```
val seq1 = (1, 2, 3)
val seq2 = (4, 5, 6)
val seq3 = (7, 8, 9)
val matrix = Seq(seq1,seq2,seq3)
```

I need to invert it, the result should be:

```
val matrix2 = matrix.inverted
println(matrix2)

Seq(Seq(1,4,7), Seq(2,5,8), Seq(3,6,9))
```

What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: This does not look like the inverse of `matrix` but its tranpose. `matrix.transpose` should do what you want, assuming `seq1`/`seq2`/`seq3` are `Seq`s, not tuples.

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is a list of tuples.

```
matrix: Seq[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
```

You can find transpose of this list of tuples using below approach

```
val transMatrix=matrix.map(tp=>List(tp._1,tp._2,tp._3)).transpose.map(lst=>(lst(0),lst(1),lst(2))).toSeq
```

The output of above approach

```
transMatrix: Seq[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,4,7), (2,5,8), (3,6,9))
```